# Is there any way to enable Ctrl+L to clear screen when 'set -o vi' is set?

Tags: bash, readline, vi-mode

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in bash default mode the screen is cleared. But when I run `set -o vi` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> the keystroke is printed (`^L`).
Is there any way to keep this behavior?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is also bound in `vi` command mode but not in insert mode. There's no default binding for `clear-screen` in insert mode. Readline bindings should be specified in `~/.inputrc`, like so:

```bsh
set editing-mode vi
$if mode=vi

set keymap vi-command
# these are for vi-command mode
Control-l: clear-screen

set keymap vi-insert
# these are for vi-insert mode
Control-l: clear-screen 
$endif
```

This will bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear the screen in both normal and insert mode. Naturally, if you prefer to only use it in one mode, just remove the relevant option.

If you prefer to set this just for `bash` use the following equivalents in `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
set -o vi
bind -m vi-command 'Control-l: clear-screen'
bind -m vi-insert 'Control-l: clear-screen'
```

There is an [extensive list of readline commands](https://web.archive.org/web/20150403162757/http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readline.htm) that you can use to customize your bash shell with.

Comment: out of curiosity, why bother with vi-command if it's already mapped? just for the sake of completeness, or is there a technical reason?

Comment: @KenBellows for clarity, as per the comments (and I needed an example in the vi-command block for purely aesthetic reasons).

Comment: @jasonwryan "set editing-mode vi" -- instead of this if the vi option is set in bash (set -o vi), then what would replace this part: $if mode=vi
 ?

Answer (score 30):

Put this line in your `bashrc`:

```
bind -m vi-insert "\C-l":clear-screen
```